# Adding dynamic preloader and percentage to flash content?

Tags: jquery, flash, web, embed, preloader

I am trying to add a dynamic preloader and I am also trying to show users the loading percentage of flash content.

I searched Google and mostly creating preloader with Adobe Flash came up. Nothing even here :(

What I am trying to do is adding this programatically.

For example if Angry birds is loading, first it should say that the flash game is loading, please be patient.

Here is the homepage: http://fullscreengame.com/

I am using PHP/Jquery. It would be really great if it is possible to do that with Jquery.

Thanks for your time,

Comment: http://blog.sebastian-martens.de/2010/05/preload-assets-with-javascript-load-complete-callback-for-single-assets-include-swfflash/ ??

Comment: Thanks Malcolm, I will try your script.